# How to deploy .NET core web and worker projects to Kubernetes in single deployment?

Tags: azure, docker, kubernetes, azure-aks, kubernetes-pod

I am relatively new to Docker and Kubernetes technologies. My requirement is to deploy one web and one worker (.Net background service) project in a single deployment.

this is how my deployment.yml file looks like :

```
apiVersion : apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: worker
spec:
  progressDeadlineSeconds: 3600
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: worker
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: worker
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: worker
          image: xxxxx.azurecr.io/worker:#{Build.BuildId}#
          #image: xxxxx.azurecr.io/web
          imagePullPolicy: Always
          #ports:
          #- containerPort: 80

apiVersion : apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: web
spec:
  progressDeadlineSeconds: 3600
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: web
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: web
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: web
          image: xxxxx.azurecr.io/web:#{Build.BuildId}#
          #image: xxxxx.azurecr.io/web
          imagePullPolicy: Always
          ports:
          - containerPort: 80
```

this is how my service.yml file looks like :

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
    name: worker
spec:
    type: LoadBalancer
    ports:
    - port: 80 
    selector:
        app: worker
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
    name: web
spec:
    type: LoadBalancer
    ports:
    - port: 80 
    selector:
        app: web
```

What I have found is if I keep both in service.yml file then its only deploying one in Kubernetes and if I comment one and execute one by one then its deploying to Kubernetes.

Is there any rule that we can’t have both in single file? Any reason why it’s not working together however working individually?

One more ask is there any way we can look into worker service pod something like taking remote of that and see what exactly going on there....even if it’s a console application then anyway to read what’s its printing on console after deployment.?

Comment: Post text as *text*, not images. Images can't be copied, googled, compiled or used to reproduce problems. Don't force people to type 70 lines by hand to reproduce your problem

Comment: Does your first file have the `---` YAML start-of-document separator between the two Deployments?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos +1 and don't forget people in China cannot open that image at all :)

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Hi Sorry I removed images. Could you please look into this?

Comment: @DavidMaze Yes it's a separator will this have any impact on the deployment like it will consider only the last one or something?

Comment: YAML doesn't strictly specify that, but I think most implementations use the last value for each key within a single document, so the first Deployment will get lost without the `---` separator.

Comment: @DavidMaze I followed the structure of the manifest from this link:https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/mslearn-tailspin-spacegame-web-kubernetes/tree/main/manifests and seems it has a work of multi-app deployment in one go.

Comment: Do you have a problem with the `deployment.yml` or `service.yml` file ?
The `service.yml` file looks good, but the `deployment.yml` doesn't have a `---` separator, as David Maze rightly pointed out.
What do you mean by `look into worker service pod` ? There is a [kubectl logs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubectl/kubectl-commands#logs) command that prints the logs for a container in a pod or specified resource.

Comment: @matt_j Thanks matt Yes having --- in deplyonemnt.yml solved the issue. Thanks ... I did not know how --- line is considered by release pipeline.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue was resolved in the comments section and I decided to provide a Community Wiki answer just for better visibility to other community members.

It is possible to group multiple Kubernetes resources in the same file, but it is important to separate them using three dashes (“`---`”).
It's also worth mentioning that resources will be created in the order they appear in the file.

For more information, see the [Organizing resource configurations](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/cluster-administration/manage-deployment/#organizing-resource-configurations) documentation.

---

I've created an example to demonstrate how we can create a simple `app-1` application (`Deployment` + `Service`) using a single manifest file:

```
$ cat app-1.yml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  labels:
    app: app-1
  name: app-1
spec:
  ports:
  - port: 80
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: 80
  selector:
    app: app-1
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  labels:
    app: app-1
  name: app-1
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: app-1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: app-1
    spec:
      containers:
      - image: nginx
        name: nginx
```

**NOTE:** Resources are created in the order they appear in the file:

```
$ kubectl apply -f app-1.yml
service/app-1 created
deployment.apps/app-1 created

$ kubectl get deploy,svc
NAME                    READY   UP-TO-DATE   
deployment.apps/app-1   1/1     1            

NAME                 TYPE        CLUSTER-IP    EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)   
service/app-1        ClusterIP   10.8.14.179   <none>        80/TCP
```